# Transform Types in RXjava

Tags: android, rx-android, rx-java2

Is it possible to convert an observable like Single to Single? I believe that the operator compose() is used for this purpose but I am lost in how to implement it

What I want to achieve here could be more clearly seen in the following code snippet.

```
@Override
public Single<SystemDefaults> getSystemDefaults() {

    SystemDefaults systemDefaults = new SystemDefaults();
    return systemDao.getRoles().compose((SingleTransformer<List<Role>, SystemDefaults>) upstream -> {
        //WHAT SHOULD I DO HERE?
    });

}
```

I am pretty new to RxJava(Android) so am pretty lost here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need the `map` operator. `Map` takes every item your `Observable`s (or `Single`s `Maybe`s, etc) and transform it to another value:

```
Observable.just(1)                                      // Start emitting Integers
              .map(number -> number.toString()})        // Transform it to String
              .subscribe(someString -> System.out.println(someString.getClass()));     // Receive an String
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes the operator you´re looking it´s compose and it´s used to transform an observable/single from your previous observable/single.

Here an example how I transform an Integer observable to String observable.

```
   Observable.Transformer<Integer, String> transformIntegerToString() {
        return observable -> observable.map(String::valueOf);
    }

    /**
     * In this example we use a transformer to get the Integer item emitted and transform to String
     */
    @Test
    public void observableWithTransformToString() {
        Observable.just(1)
                  .map(number -> {
                      System.out.println("Item is Integer:" + Integer.class.isInstance(number));
                      return number;
                  })
                  .compose(transformIntegerToString())
                  .subscribe(number -> System.out.println("Item is String:" + (String.class.isInstance(number))));

    }
```

You can see another example how to change it to another observable in another thread here. https://github.com/politrons/reactive/blob/master/src/test/java/rx/observables/transforming/ObservableCompose.java

Comment: Your use of `map` here is a bit weird. Shouldn't it be more convenient to use `doOnNext()`?

Comment: While I really appreciate you teaching me how to use compose , the answer below was what I was looking for. Ty

Comment: Yes you can just use Map or FlaMap to modify your obsrrvable value. Compose is to create just a new Observable/Single not just mutate the value that contains.